# xmlhttprequest in chrome extension

Tags: xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-extension, http-post

I am developing a chrome extension and I have an iframe which I use in my extension. This is what I do with my iframe

"When I drag and drop a image to my iframe I handle the drop event in one of the content scripts and pass that function call my extension code. There I create a xmlhttprequest object and then send the URL of the image to a php file in my server."

This is what is happening. I get a readyState of "4" but there is no POST request going out of my browser. I checked with the "NETWORK" tab in the browser but there is no POST request going out of the browser (I have listed my site in the permissions section of the manifest file).

**This is my code --.>**

***JScript.js(One of the content scripts )***

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
    var imgurl=$(ui.draggable).attr('src');
    imgurl="IMGURL="+imgurl;
    _post("www.somedomain.come/testing.php",imgurl,function(result){ alert("success")});
    }
```

***This is my proxy in the same content script-->***

```
  _post = function(url, data, callback) 
    {
      console.log("sending post");
      chrome.extension.sendRequest({
      msgType:'post', 
      data: data, 
      url:url
      }, function(response){
        alert(response);
     });
    }
```

***This my OnRequest function handler in background.html -->***

```
 chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
  if (request.msgType === 'post') {
        alert("Now in OnRequest function");
        // console.log("Now in Onrequest Function");
        alert("Url: "+request.url + "\n Data : "+ request.data);
        ajaxcallingfunction(request);
        alert("completed the ajax call");
        sendResponse("success");
      }

    });

var ajaxcallingfunction = function(request){
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open("POST",request.url, false);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    alert(xhr.readyState);
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            alert(xhr.readyState);
        }
    }       
    xhr.send(request.data);
   alert("after xhr call");
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `http://` in front of your url, right?

`xhr.readyState` doesn't tell much, it just means that it is done. Check out what's inside `xhr.status`, it would contain error code. If everything is ok it should be `200`:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        alert(xhr.status);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked but now the problem is I am able to send the request but not the data. Whenever I try to get the URL of the image it is coming as an empty string. My php script uses simple $_POST["IMGURL"] array to get the url of the image. Any idea why I am always getting an empty string? I am sure I am having the data(url of the image) before sending it to the server. Am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: @Ajai Open network tab in chrome console and check what data is sent in that request. If all looks ok then do `print_r($_POST)` on php side and check what is received.